# Copying source files and retaining folder structures including parent folders (but not files)

Tags: powershell, robocopy

Say I have the following source and target.

**source:** c:\temp\folder1\folder2

**target:** e:\backup

I want to have an output as shown below. As you can see, it should only copy the files and its subdirectories from the above source path but it should also copy/create the parent folders (no files) leading to the source path. How can I accomplish this with Powershell or robocopy? If Powershell doesnt handle long path names then I prefer using Robocopy.

**source:**
c:\temp
\folder1
\file1.txt
\folder2
\file2.txt
\folder3
\file3.txt

**output:**
e:\backup
\temp
\folder1
\folder2
\file2.txt
\folder3
\file3.txt

Comment: Please share your coding at solving the problem

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood you right you want to create any missing folders in the output on the fly. In powershell this would be s.t. like this:

```
Copy-Item c:\temp e:\backup\temp\ -recurse
```